# _idx and _tmp suffixed tables

Tags: database, indexing

we can see some tables have the suffix of `_idx` and `_tmp` in magento database,

but these tables doesn't have any data (whenever I see the tables using MySQL client),

what is the usage of these tables in magento ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are used **during indexing** to prepare new data for the actual index tables and are truncated afterwards.

Comment: but cataloginventory_stock_status_idx, catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx, catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx and some other have datum, it is not truncated? is it due to incomplete indexing?

Comment: I had a quick look and actually at least some of the indexers truncate *before* indexing, not afterwards. So, nothing wrong there.